# Building GCC 4.6 - libmpfr.so.4 - cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, gcc, configuration

I'm trying to build GCC 4.6 under CentOS release 5.5 (Final). I've freshly built GMP-5.0.1, MPC-0.9, and MPFR-3.0.1, and have used the following configure command:

**../configure --prefix=/users/xxxx/apps/mygcc4.6 --disable-checking --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-mpfr=/users/xxxx/code/gcc/mpfr-3.0.1-install-cyprus --with-gmp=/users/xxxx/code/gcc/gmp-5.0.1-install-cyprus --with-mpc=/users/xxxx/code/gcc/mpc-0.9-install-cyprus**

After this, I run make and after about 5 minutes get the following error message:

**checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/users/xxxx/code/gcc/gcc-4.6.0/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See`config.log' for more details.**

The config.log indicates that a recently generated program (cc1) is involved:

**/users/xxxx/code/gcc/gcc-4.6.0/obj/./gcc/cc1**

Indeed if I run this program with no arguments I get the same error message found in config.log:

**error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

However, libmpfr.so.4 is in the lib subdirectory of that provided to configure using the --with-mpfr flag, as seen above. I have LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH empty. Any idea how I can get past this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your library is acutally in the directory given and not in some `lib` subdirectory. Use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/users/xxxx/code/gcc/mpfr-3.0.1-install-cyprus` as you have already suggested ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but accidentally not to the lib subdirectory. Ok, it looks like gmp should also be there, so I'll try now with all three...

Comment: It worked: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/users/xxxx/code/gcc/mpfr-3.0.1-install-cyprus/lib:/users/xxxx/code/gcc/gmp-5.0.1-install-cyprus/lib:/users/xxxx/code/gcc/mpc-0.9-install-cyprus/lib`

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is pretty outdated.  But, I had to comment and say that after 5+ hours of banging my head against the wall on a very similar issue (checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile) and having read the install manual, a multitude of forums, and trying various things on the system in question I found this brief but very useful post.  The issue was precisely related to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Long story short, when building from source if you hit this wall export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to point into the source build directory for the libs.
Worked for me anyway.

Good luck folks.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is pretty outdated. I faced similar issues while installing [mpfr](https://www.mpfr.org/) on WSL. The build was fine and mpfr installed correctly but when I wrote a small C file to see if I could access the header file and print the version fo the installation - I could compile the C file but When I tried to run the compiled object - it would give me an error. The C file was,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

int main (void) {
    printf ("MPFR library: %-12s\nMPFR header: %s (based on %d.%d.%d)\n",
    mpfr_get_version (), MPFR_VERSION_STRING, MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR,
    MPFR_VERSION_MINOR, MPFR_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);
    return 0;
}
```

I was compiling this with,

```
gcc -o version mpfr_presence.c -lmpfr -lgmp
```

But when I tried to run this with `./version`, I would get the following error,

```
./version: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I solved this error using,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmpfr4
```

And then when it said that `libmpfr4` was already at its latest version, just to be sure,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmpfr4
```

Now `./version` gives me,

```
MPFR library: 4.0.1
MPFR header: 4.0.1 (based on 4.0.1)
```